# How to set a Set Handler for proxy request

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2.4, apache-modules

So what I want is when client send request a Apache HTTP Server it should pass to back end server and then when response comes to Apache  HTTP Server, it should be modified using **set handler** in the server and send response back to client.

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>

            #ServerName www.example.com
            #ProxyPreserveHost On
            ServerName localhost
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com

            ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/user/userlist
            ProxyBadHeader Ignore
            <Location / >

                    SetHandler proxyMod
                    #ProxyPassReverse http://0.0.0.0:8080/user/userlist
            </Location>

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
```

But it will not send to set handler. just pass to client what ever the back end server gives.

Comment: Does this help http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#handler?

Comment: I tried that but  I did not get how to use                                         <FilesMatch> I f you can explain it would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be writing a module rather.
Hope bellow documentation helps.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes actually what I understood was completely wrong. If you want to this king of thing you should use FastCGI or CGI (http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/) and you can use reverse proxy to handle this. Here is the sample Apache virtual host configuration file

```
     <VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName localhost
    #ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off
    LogLevel debug

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/keys/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/keys/ca.key
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com

    ProxyPass /apimanager/user/signup https://localhost/api/routing_index
    ProxyPassReverse /apimanager/user/signp https://localhost/api/routing_index



    ScriptAlias /api/ /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

  # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```